# How to modify test results' output in mocha.js (or another library)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am creating a test suite that will be run by mocha. In the test, I plan on using `should` and `chai` at the very least. I am testing JSON objects. I want mocha to be silent about successful tests and I want to control what the errors look like at the end of the run. Right now, there is a lot of red text describing the JSON object and other information. What I want is to override the output.

Here is an example test for an element in the JSON object which I would import from `testData`.

```
var should = require("should");
var chai = require("chai");
var expect = chai.expect;

const testData = require("./testData");

for (t of testData.data) {
        describe("This will fail", function() {

                it("Should have a zipperNut",function(done) {

                        t.should.have.property('zipperNut');
                        done();
                });
        });
}
```

What I want is to see just this:

```
$ mocha testSuite.js
zipperNut
$
```

And so on for all the tests I want to run. Can I do this? Do I need to use a different library?

Comment: This seems like an interesting place to look: https://mochajs.org/api/tutorial-custom-reporter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha's output is determined by something called a "default reporter". If you want to change the output you can specify a different reporter, which is presumably available through npm or similar. To specify a new custom reporter you do this:

`$ mocha --reporter my-reporter.js`

Where my-reporter.js is the file containing my "reporter". For me, I just want the plain name of the failing tests, so my reporter would look like:

```
'use strict';

const Mocha = require('mocha');
const {
  EVENT_RUN_END,
  EVENT_TEST_FAIL,
} = Mocha.Runner.constants;

class MyReporter {
  constructor(runner) {
    const stats = runner.stats;

    runner
      .on(EVENT_TEST_FAIL, (test, err) => {
        console.log(
          `${test.title}`
        );
      })
      .once(EVENT_RUN_END, () => {
        console.log(`end: ${stats.passes}/${stats.passes + stats.failures} ok`);
      });
  }
}

module.exports = MyReporter;
```

Documentation here:

https://mochajs.org/api/tutorial-custom-reporter.html